# Rotating ellipse perimeter analysis

Tags: differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I was wondering how the visible ellipse perimeter changes while rotating the ellipse in space. I am not mathematician, but I suppose the issue is probably more complex than it seems, so let's make some assumptions as follow:

- the major to minor semiaxes ratio is $1.4$
- we use the approximate ellipse perimeter equation $L \approx 2\pi \sqrt{\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}}$
- we rotate the ellipse around the major semi-axis (i.e. '$x$-line' - please see the [PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmbDT.jpg)).

I would very gladly compare this function with the change in visible semi-minor axis length to see how the differences of the two parameters interplay during rotation.

I am MD measuring congenital heart defects so I do not need the analysis to be very complex - the briefer the better.

Thank you for your interest.

Comment: You may use the better approximation $L\approx 2\pi\left(\frac{a^{3/2}+b^{3/2}}{2}\right)^{2/3}$. Now it is not difficult to understand how the apparent $a$ and $b$ change during a rotation of our ellipse in the 3d-space.

Comment: If you fix the ratio of semi-major to semi-minor axes ($\dfrac{a}{b}=1.4$ here), the perimeter won't change.  Can you clarify more?  Or just you want to compare the shapes among prolate and oblate ellipsoids.

Comment: @NgChungTak - I don't want to fix the ratio, I give you the ellipse with a/b=1.4 and observe it rotating, measuring its visible perimeter. If you want me to clarify: originally we see the figure with its "baseline" perimeter, but when we rotate it by 90o we just see a line which length equals 2a. What I want to know is how the visible or better said measurable perimeter changes between these 2 moments.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Well, it is still not very clear to me. All I know is that the visible a is constant, I don't conclude it from the equation, though.

Comment: @JanHenzel What's mean by visible perimeter?  Did you want to plot $L$ versus $a$ and $b$?  In such case, there's nothing relevant to rotation.

Comment: @NgChungTak Please imagine an ovoid shape rotating in space as I showed in the picture. By visible perimeter I mean the perimeter I can see and measure while it is rotating.

Comment: Where is the viewpoint relative to the ellipse? The resulting image of the ellipse depends on the projection that you use to simulate what’s “visible.”

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha$ be a plane containing your ellipse $\Gamma$, let $a$ be the major semi-axis lenght of $\Gamma$, $b$ the minor semi-axis lenght of $\Gamma$ and let $\beta$ be another plane containing the major axis of $\Gamma$.
Let $\theta$ denote the angle between $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
The orthogonal projection of $\Gamma$ on $\beta$ is an ellipse $\Psi$ with the same major-axis lenght and semi-minor axis lenght given by $b\cos(\theta)$.
[image]
The visible perimeter is then the perimeter $L'$ of $\Psi$ which is given by:
$$L'\approx 2\pi \sqrt{\dfrac{a^2+b^2\cos^2(\theta)}{2}}$$

Comment: Thank you Fabio, this is exactly what I meant, I do apprecaite your interest. Just one more question if you please: what will be the 'visible' b change, is it b'=bcos(theta)?

Comment: Yes, this is the lenght of projected (i.e. visible) minor semi-axis.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wouldnt be able to figure it out on my own.

Comment: Great, glad it was helpful! Please accept an answer with the checkmark to the left so the question is marked as 'resolved' in the system.